# Find the K-th last element of a singly linked list - getting undefined

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm trying to solve this kata [Find the K-th last element of a singly linked list](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5810d8ce2956d78698000032/train/javascript):

> Write a function that given the head of singly linked list, and an
> index (0 based) counted from the end of the list, returns the element
> corresponding to that index.
>
> The function must return a falsy value for invalid input values, like
> an out of range index.
>
> So for the list `66 -> 42 -> 13 -> 666`, getKthLastElement() with index
> 2 should return the Node (predefined object for list nodes)
> corresponding to 42.

I don't understand why I get undefined instead of number in my `return`. I tried this code in a codepen, and everything worked fine, and the result is number, but in CodeWars it's undefined.

```js
function getKthLastElement(head, k) {
  let arr = [];
  while(head){
    arr.push(head.data);
    head = head.next
  }
  if(k == 0) k = 1
  let result = arr.splice(-k, 1)
  return +result
}
```

Comment: The test is expecting result with property `data` as you can see here `getKthLastElement(list, 0).data` . You are only returning a number and it doesn't have a property of `data` thus you are getting `undefined`, so if you do `return { data: +result };` should solve your issue of `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

When you read the code challenge, you see it asks to return the k<sup>th</sup> *element*, the `Node` instance, not the *value*.

So you shouldn't collect `head.data`, but `head`. And not return `+result`, but `result[0]`.

Another issue is that you treat `k` as 1 when it has value 0, but this is not what it says in the description. A value of 0 has a different meaning than a value of 1. Instead you should always increase `k` with 1.

Then there is the requirement to return a falsy value when the value of `k` is out of range. You did not provide code for that case.

So here is the corrected code:

```
function getKthLastElement(head, k) {
  let arr = [];
  while(head){
    arr.push(head); // Collect the node, not the value
    head = head.next;
  }

  if (k < 0 || k >= arr.length) return; // Out of range
  let result = arr.splice(-(k+1), 1); // Always add 1 to k 
  return result[0]; // Return the node.
}
```

This works, but it is not memory efficient. By turning the whole list into an array, you allocated O(n) auxiliary memory. You should try to do it without such an array.

Here is a spoiler which I hope you don't need:

> `function getKthLastElement(head, k) {
>    let lead = head;
>    let lag = head;
>    if (k < 0) return; // k is out of range
>    for (let i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
>      if (!lead) return; // k is out of range
>      lead = lead.next;
>    }
>    while(lead) {
>      lead = lead.next;
>      lag = lag.next;
>    }
>    return lag;
>  }`